# Passing class type to generic

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

In the following code how can i pass a class to responseType ?

```
func sendGetRequest(url:String,
                   request: String,
                   responseType: AnyClass,
                  completion: (AnyObject?, ServerError?)-> Void) {
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
      .validate()
      .responseObject { (response: Response<**responseType**, NSError>) in

...

}
```

Currently AnyClass is not working it says "responseType is not a type"
If i replace responseType with actual class it works. But i want to make the function generic and responseType can be of any class to map properly.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the method that you are trying to use:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=responseObject

Then the issue is that AnyClass is not conforming to ResponseObjectSerializable, you could extend AnyClass to include the required methods for ResponseObjectSerializable, or you could make your method param take ResponseObjectSerializable instead of anyClass

Comment: Ok i got it. I missed the confirming to ResponseObjectSerializable part. Thanks.